# Install custom version of node with apt-get

Tags: apt, versions, nodejs

I've installed nodejs this way:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

The thing is it installs node v 0.10.24. Is there there a way I can install nodejs 0.10.23 only just temporarily so I can do an easy `apt-get update` later so it can be once again the latest version?

Is it possible to do with with `apt-get` and not use other tools (like nvm or building from source)?

Answer (score 0):

The specific version you require is not available in the PPA to be used with `apt`, but it has been built and is available for download as separate files on the [`repository's builds list`](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/+builds?build_state=built).

Just download the version+release+arch desired file and install it with `dpkg -i nodejs.deb`.

Don't forget that if after installing the desired version of nodejs an `apt-get upgrade` will update the current version to the latest version, so you will need to [pin the package so that it is not updated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package).